# Kyber PKE correctness proof, how is triangle inequality used

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, kyber

Im reading the [CRYSTALS kyber paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) and am stuck on the PKE correctness proof on page 5. I can't see how the triangle inequality would help to get to the result $|| \lceil q / 2 \rfloor \cdot (m - m') ||_\infty < 2 \cdot \lceil q / 4 \rfloor$.

Answer (score 6):

They must be using the $\|a\|-\|b\| \le \|a+b\|$ variant of the triangle inequality (see [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInequality.html)).

For those of you following along, this is all at the end of page 5. They start with the following fact:

$$
\bigl\| w + \lceil q/2 \rfloor \cdot m - \lceil q/2 \rfloor \cdot m' \bigr\|_\infty \le \lceil q/4 \rfloor.
$$

Apply the triangle inequality that I wrote above (with $b=w$), to get:

$$
-\bigl\| w \bigr\|_\infty  + \bigl\| \lceil q/2 \rfloor \cdot m - \lceil q/2 \rfloor \cdot m' \bigr\|_\infty \le \lceil q/4 \rfloor.
$$

Then move $\|w\|_\infty$ to the right hand side, and use the fact that $\|w\|_\infty < \lceil q/4\rfloor$ to finally get:

$$
\bigl\| \lceil q/2 \rfloor \cdot m - \lceil q/2 \rfloor \cdot m' \bigr\|_\infty < 2 \lceil q/4 \rfloor.
$$

Comment: The authors then go on to write that for all odd $q$ it implies that $m = m'$. Why is this the case? Does this follow from a "coefficient comparison"?